# Why did fetch() API failed to retrieve custom HIBP JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I am trying to use the [Have I Been Pwned?](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2) API to retrieve a list of breaches for a given email account.

I retrieve this list using the fetch() API. In the browser it looks like there is a connection to the [HIBP](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) website but the expected breaches are not visible.

I think this is a JSON problem because the API returns results without a root tree (?) (e.g. [breaches:{"Name"... - only the {"Name"}), so I think I'm making a mistake at the iteration step in the JS file. Also, I'm not calling the 'retrieve' function in the HTML file correctly because the browser throws an error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: retrieve is not defined', but this is a side-issue (fetch('https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/test@example.com') doesn't work either).

This is my first week working with JS, fetch(), and JSON, so I consulted a couple of sources before asking this question (but I still can't figure it out, after a couple of days):

1. [How to Use the JavaScript Fetch API to Get Data](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data)
2. [fetch API](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch)
3. [API methods for HaveIBeenPwnd.com (unofficial)](https://github.com/fvdm/nodejs-haveibeenpwned)

Where is the actual problem?

The **index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    </head>

    <body id="top">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="content">
                <h1 style="text-align: center">Put an email in this box</h1>
                <input type="email" id="InputBox" value="" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" />
                <button type="submit" id="PwnedButton" onclick="retrieve">pwned?</button>
                <ul id="results"></ul>
            </div>
        </header>

        <script src="test.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The **test.js** file (I know that JS is an interpreted language - so empty characters affect execution speed - but I made it more readable for this example):

```
function createNode(element) {
    return document.createElement(element); // Create the type of element you pass in the parameters
}
function append(parent, el) {
    return parent.appendChild(el); // Append the second parameter(element) to the first one
}
const account = document.getElementById('InputBox');
const PwnedButton = document.getElementById('PwnedButton');
const results = document.getElementById('results');

fetch('https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/' + account)
    .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json

    .then(function(retrieve) {
        let breaches = retrieve.Name; // Get the results

        return breaches.map(function(check) { // Map through the results and for each one run the code below
            let span = createNode('span'); //  Create the element we need (breach title)
            span.innerHTML = `${breaches}`;
            append(results, span);
        })
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

Comment: `breaches.map` and inside the map callback (why map., you don't return anything) you use the whole `breaches`

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: retrieve is not defined` that can't be the error you get with that code

Comment: I used the code provided by the first source, originally. I don't know what .map does. And yes, that is the error I get when I click on the button.

Comment: it can't be, because `retrieve` would be the parsed JSON (an array in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> let breaches = retrieve.Name;
> ```

`retrieve` is not an object with a `Name` property.

It is an **array** containing multiple objects, each of which has a `Name` property.

You have to loop over it.

e.g.

```
retrieve.forEach( item => {
    let breaches = retrieve.Name;
    console.log(breaches);
});
```

---

> ```
> breaches.map
> ```

… and the Name is a string, so you can't map it. You can only map an array (like the one you have in `retrieve`).

Answer (score 0):

I have created working version of what are you possible going to implement, taking `Name` field from result. https://jsfiddle.net/vhnzm1fu/1/ Please notice:

```
return retrieve.forEach(function(check) {
    let span = createNode('span');
    span.innerHTML = `${check.Name}<br/>`;
    append(results, span);
})
```

Comment: Tahnks, Sergii!